# Reading and writing different registers in MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

In multi-cycle implementation is possible to read a register say RegA and write a different register say RegB in the same clock cycle ? If yes , can we read a register say RegA and write to the register in same clock cycle( where the read will be give me the previous value)?

Comment: Yes. This can be done with multiporting and phased access. E.g., the MIPS R2000 used phased access where register read was done in the later half of a cycle (in the second pipeline stage) and register write was done in the earlier half of the cycle (in the fifth pipeline stage).